# Split a polygon every time a new centerline line segment begins?

Tags: line, polygon-creation

I'm trying to sample out a road into equal parts. It was easy to do this with a line segment using the split tool because I couldn't figure out a way to break the polygon in the photo every 150ft but was able to easily with a line segment.

Would it be possible to break the polygon to match the extent of the line segments shown below? Each different color is a new 150ft segment. I have QGIS and Arcmap 10.5.1

[image: Example]

Comment: You've neglected to mention which software you are using and license level.